# \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle} I cannot have more that 14pt

Tags: untagged

On my last Latex doc, I use this document class to let me use the font show there

```
\setmainfont{industry-blackitalic}
```

but I can't use more that 14 pt for the biggest of char. I would use 16 or 18, but if I go over 14, my text became small.
what can I do?

Thank you

Renato

Comment: with any class you can go `\fontsize{3cm}{4cm}\selectfont ABC` if you want big letters.

Comment: sorry, how  can I use it? Where do I have to insert it?

Comment: try this with lualatex or xelatex `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{3cm}{4cm}\selectfont ABC
\end{document}`

Comment: There are several packages, that provide other font sizes, e.g., [`scrextend`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) or [`fontsize`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontsize). And some classes like [`scrartcl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) also allow such sizes.

Comment: Have you tried using the \fontsize command to specify the size you want? For example, to set the font size to 18pt, you could use \fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont, where 22 is the value for the baseline skip (usually set to 1.2 times the font size).

Comment: The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) provides for font sizes from 4pt to 132pt. Read the documentation section 3.2 "Font sizes".

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at `extarticle.cls`:

```
\DeclareOption{8pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{8}}
\DeclareOption{9pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{9}}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{10}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{11}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{12}}
\DeclareOption{14pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{14}}
\DeclareOption{17pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{17}}
\DeclareOption{20pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{20}}
```

So if you choose `17pt` or `20pt` you'll get them *provided* you load also `fix-cm` (in case your document uses the standard Computer Modern fonts) or a package that supports scalable fonts. In the former case, you should add

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

*before* `\documentclass`.

Specifying other options is useless, because they're not recognized. If you want an arbitrary font size, there's the `fontsize` package:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=18pt]{fontsize}

\begin{document}

\fontname\font

\Large\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]